# PDO query with 2 params in 1 variable

Tags: php, pdo

I have problem with inserting into database when i want to save 2 variables in 1 row.

Here i got form where i want when i put name, and select all other things to save me a items i choose and enter in specified color to save in database in that color.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend> Add user </legend>
    <p><label class="field" for="user">User :</label> <input type="text" name="user" id="user"></label></p>
    <p><label class="field" for="roll">Points :</label> 
    <select name="roll_chance" id="roll">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
        <option value="**">**</option>
        <option value="***">***</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><label class="field" for="class">Class :</label>
    <select name="class" id="class">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Assasin">Assasin</option>
        <option value="Bard">Bard</option>
        <option value="Mage">Mage</option>
        <option value="Marksman">Marksman</option>
        <option value="Protector">Protector</option>
        <option value="Priest">Priest</option>
        <option value="Reaper">Reaper</option>
        <option value="Tormentor">Tormentor</option>
        <option value="Vampire">Vampire</option>
        <option value="Warrior">Warrior</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><label class="field" for="color">Color :</label>
    <select name="color" id="color">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['roll_chance']) && isset($_POST['class']) && isset($_POST['color'])) {
        $user = htmlentities($_POST['user']);
        $roll = htmlentities($_POST['roll_chance']);
        $class = htmlentities($_POST['class']);
        $color = htmlentities($_POST['color']);

        $user = strip_tags($user);
        $roll = strip_tags($roll);
        $class = strip_tags($class);
        $color = strip_tags($color);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO users (user, roll_chance, class) VALUES (:user, :roll, :class)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':user', '<span style"color:'.$color.';">'.$user.'</span>');
        $stmt->bindParam(':roll', $roll);
        $stmt->bindParam(':class', '<span style"color:'.$color.';">'.$class.'</span>');
        $stmt->execute();
    }   
}
```

Comment: How about creating another Row "color"? :D Because what you try to do make no sense.You never want to save two attributes in one row. Simply create another row, name it color and then select those and in output it like you're trying to insert now ;)

Comment: Please explain what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise to split data and layout and create a column named `color` in your table. And change query like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO users (user, roll_chance, class, color) VALUES (:user, :roll, :class, :color)");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':roll', $roll);
$stmt->bindParam(':class', $class);
// insert color
$stmt->bindParam(':color', $color);
$stmt->execute();
```

And use this `color` value later in your output.
This will make your life easier if later you'll need to change layout from `span` to `div` or other markup.

Comment: Oh i forgot totally about this one, thank u very much for answer and tips.